# Чтобы программа на всех размерах экранов была одинаковой в tkinter на Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать так, чтобы программа была одинаковой на всех размерах экранов в tkinter на python. Я пишу программу на компе для телефонов, и когда я её тестировал, то она смотрелась совсем не так, как на компе. Там все кнопки, строки, и все остальное сместилось в одну кучку. Помогите пожалуйста!
Вот код:

```
import sys
import random
import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()

category6 = [("Присядь 5 раз"), ("Пригни 3 раза")]
length_category6 = len(category6)

category12 = [("Присядь 10 раз"), ("Пригни 5 раза")]
length_category12 = len(category12)

sos = 0

def button_click1(event):
    global sos
    sos = 1  
    event = random.randrange(0, length_category6)

def button_click2(event):
    global sos
    sos = 2    
    event = random.randrange(0, length_category12)

def ura(event): 
    global sos
    if sos == 1:
        mlabe12.config(text = 'Задание: ' + category6[event], bg = 'White')
    elif sos == 2:
        mlabe12.config(text = 'Задание: ' + category12[event], bg = 'White')

mbutton = Tk.Button(text = 'Готово', command = lambda: ura, fg = 'Black', bg = 
'Orange', width = 16, height = 2)
mbutton.bind("<Button-1>", ura)
mbutton.place(x = 100, y = 345)

root["bg"] = "Light green"
root.geometry('315x500+500+300')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)

mlabel = Tk.Label(root, text = '                      Выбери возрастную 
категорию:                      
', bg = 'Light blue', font = "Arial 10", height = 2)
mlabel.pack()

vlab = Tk.Label(text = " ", width = 70, height = 15, bg = "Light Blue")
vlab.place(x = 0, y = 400)

vbat1 = Tk.Button(text="6+", width = 5, height = 2, bg = "Pink", fg = 
"Black")
vbat1.bind("<Button-1>", button_click1)
vbat1.place(x = 110, y = 432)

vbat2 = Tk.Button(text = "12+", width = 5, height = 2, bg = "Green", fg = 
"Black")
vbat2.bind("<Button-1>", button_click2)
vbat2.place(x = 165, y = 432)

flab = Tk.Label(text = "", width = 70, height = 1, bg = "Yellow")
flab.place(x = 0, y = 400)

ylab = Tk.Label(text = " ", bg = "Yellow", height = 4, width = 70)
ylab.place(x = 0, y = 482)

mlabe12 = Tk.Label(root)
mlabe12.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Через tkinter разве возможно делать приложения для телефонов?

Comment: Объективно без какого-либо кода или хотя бы скиншотов проблемы невозможно Вам помочь

Comment: Ладно, тогда я скину часть кода

Comment: Вот, я код переместил в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Используйте относительные размеры с помощью атрибутов place relx и rely
например:

`label = Label(root, text='Hello')
 label.place(relx=0,25, rely=0,5)`

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Когда я поставил нужные координаты на компе, то все нормально, но когда я тоже самое тестировал на моем телефоне, то оно слегка смещено, но спасибо что дали нужное направление